# Best way to create shared environment variables between AWS ElasticBeanstalk applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking to find a way to share secrets from between ElasticBeanstalk applications.

My current thought process is to have an ebextension file and have that run in each of my applications to populate these shared secrets, but I'm wondering if there is a way to have shared environment variables in some form or another.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Should be tagged as a duplicate; issue is well covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490745/how-to-specify-sensitive-environment-variables-at-deploy-time-with-elastic-beans

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked into that post, and from its content it is why I tentatively decided to move forward with an ebextensions method. I would say this is different in that I'm looking to see if there are other alternatives, perhaps some sort of environment configuration inheritance or something I am unaware of.

Comment: If ebextensions is the way to go I'm more than happy to move forward with that solution.

Comment: ebxtensions + externally defined value of environment property is the simplest solution. If you want to make yourself really busy, you can try AWS Secrets Manager + CloudFormation template + environment property (middle of the [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html))